# elasticsearch create two types from a single type

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

My data in elastic search was exported like this in my_index/type1

```
{"id" : 1, "title" : "a", "type" : "type1", "desc" :"d" }
{"id" : 2, "title" : "x", "type" : "type2", "desc" :"e" }
{"id" : 3, "title" : "y", "type" : "type1", "desc" :"e" }
{"id" : n, "title" : "z", "type" : "type1", "desc" :"f" }
```

Now, I think it will be more convenient if every line with type1 would be in my_index/type1, and every line with type2 would move to my_index/type2.

I was wondering if there was a simple way to do that?

Since I still have my json file, I could write a java program that would extract every line with type1 in a file, and every line with type2 in another file. Then use the bulk api to create two types. But I was wondering if there was a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is not a direct method available so you might go loop search method. can you use javascript to your json data?

Comment: Using more than 1 `_type` in an index is not recommended. If you're going ahead with this, you might want to consider splitting this up in 2 indices. You can use the Reindex API with a `_type` to split the existing index.

Comment: @VinodKumar I don't know. The json file is used for indexing, so I guess not.

Comment: @LoekvanGool Thank you, I am going to use your option then, it seems promising!

Comment: Using more than one type in an index is perfectly ok as long as both types share most of their fields. However, going forth, since in ES 6 types are going to [disappear](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-6-0-0-alpha1-released), you might want to already plan for this and go with the solution suggested by @LoekvanGool

Comment: But don't forget that too many indices are also an issue. One of the migration paths for the removal of types is actually to use `_type` and make it a regular `type` field, which you can easily filter on. This is exactly what you have at the moment, so your current implementation might be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Val They say they will remove it completely in ES 7. But the point stull stands.

Comment: @NoSmile What is the cardinality of your `type` field, i.e. how many different values does it contain?

Comment: @Val Only type1 and type2, that's why I thought it would be better to split them into two categories.

Comment: I don't think it'd make any difference to split them... The only reason could be if you have a huge amount of docs and want to split them in 2> indexes.

Comment: okay thanks, I am going to stick on a single index then!

Comment: And here is the whole story that Elastic just published on their blog: https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-type-parent-child-join-now-future-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Thank you. I had heard about elastic search from an outside blog, stating that type is like table and index is like database. Therefore, I felt it was better to split them.